# MapReduce() taking longer than for loop

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

**The Story**

I am supporting a GAE webapp that exports data. Currently it dumps an ndb table into a csv file using a for loop. The for loop is taking too long at this point (~25 min), and doesn't always finished before the job needs to move to a different machine. I tried to use MapReduce() shorten the the job, but my MapReduce() job runs for hours without any significant output, errors, logs, anything. The mapper doesn't finish and it doesn't ever even try to write to BQ. I'm sure I'm missing something. Any advice would be helpful.

**The Code** (Some variable names have been changed to protect their identity)

Original For Loop

```
more = True
cursor = None
formatted_rows = []
query = NDBTable.query()
while more:
    rows, cursor, more = query.fetch_page(page_size=5000, start_cursor=cursor)
    try:
        formatted_rows += [datastore_map(row) for row in rows]
    except Timeout, e:
        error_msg = "{}\nThe Datastore timed out while trying to map the row export for \n{}".format(repr(e), rows)
    logging.error(error_msg)


filename = '/filepath'
gcs_file = gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type='text/csv')

output = StringIO.StringIO()
output.write('Column headers')
output.write('\n')
for row in formatted_rows:
    output.write(str(row))

if len(output.getvalue()) > 0:
    gcs_file.write(output.getvalue())
    output.close()
    gcs_file.close()
```

datastore_map()

```
def datastore_map(entity_type):
    try:
        data = entity_type.to_dict()
    except ValueError, e:
        error_msg = "Problem loading entity to dict: {e}".format(e=repr(e))
        logging.error(error_msg)
        yield ''

    try:
        value6 = OtherNDBTable.query(OtherNDBTable.value == data.value)
    except AttributeError, e:
        warn_msg = "Could not get the value for row {row_dict}\n{msg}".format(row_dict=data, msg=repr(e))
        value6 = ""
        logging.warning(warn_msg)

    try:
        result_list = [
            data.get('value1'),
            data.get('value2'),
            data.get('value3'),
            data.get('value4'),
            data.get('value5'),
            value6
        ]
    except Exception, e:
        logging.warning("Other Exception: {} for \n {}".format(repr(e), data))
        yield ''
    result = ','.join(['"%s"' % field for field in result_list])
    yield "%s\n" % result
```

MapReduce() Pipeline

```
class DatastoreMapperPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, entity_type):
        outputs = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
            "Datastore Mapper %s" % entity_type,
            "main.datastore_map",
            "mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
            output_writer_spec="mapreduce.output_writers.FileOutputWriter",
            params={
                "input_reader": {
                    "entity_kind": entity_type,
                },
                "output_writer": {
                    "filesystem": "gs",
                    "gs_bucket_name": GS_BUCKET,
                    "output_sharding": "none",
                }
            },
            shards=X) #X has been 10, 36, and 500 with no difference
        yield CloudStorageToBigQuery(outputs) # Doesn't get here

    def finalized(self):
        logging.debug("Pipeline {} has finished with outputs {}".format(self.pipeline_id, self.outputs))
```

**Closing**

App engine logs only start the the url that kicks off the jobs returned a code of 200. Nothing else appears in any logs. The MapReduce() dashboard shows the the jobs is running and all of the shards running the job. The last work item for each shard is unknown though and its Time eplapsed is only a few seconds even the the run has an overall time elapsed of hours.
If you need anything else posted to help answer, let me know.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: did you call `start()` on the pipeline in the handler?

Comment: Hi, I'm Mario, a representative of Google Cloud Platform. Were you able to solve this issue or still need help with it? Thanks.

Comment: Actually i need help with this. I have a 200 MB file, i am also using a combiner to fasten up the process on a dual-core 4GB system. My mapper is running for more than an hour. I see the records getting generated but it too slow. mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb=300,mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize=10000000,mapred.reduce.parallel.copies=2 has been set. But in vain please help.